# How do I set this checkbox to unchecked as a default

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox in PHP that automatically becomes checked when the page loads.

```
<?php $data = array('name'=> 'checkAllId', 'id'=> 'checkAllId','style'=> 'float: left; margin-right: 10px;"' ); ?>
 <span style="width:200px; float:left"><?=form_checkbox($data).' '.form_label('All Permissions');?></span>
```

How do i default the checkbox to unchecked when the page loads?

Comment: So how is that checkbox created? What does `form_checkbox()` do?

Comment: the form_checkbox() function creates the checkbox with the data it gets from the array $data

Comment: I figured as much, but how does it create it? We can't know without seeing this function. It's probably better changing how the box is created in the first place than changing its checked status after page load with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**:

```
$('#checkAllId').prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  `'checked' => FALSE` to your $data array.

And please next time mention what framework you are using, this is CI for example.

Comment: functions form_checkbox and form_label are not standard PHP functions, I assume you are using CodeIgniter (as they exists in it). Not all people can know out of the box what you are using.